# typescript: define the type of a classes collection

Tags: object, typescript, collections, types

i don't know how to define the type of class's collection in typescript:

When i compile the following code, i've got an error:

```
    class Wall{
        brick: string;

        constructor(){
            this.brick = "jolies briques oranges";
        }

        // Wall methods ...
    }

class Critter {
    CritterProperty1: string[];
    CritterProperty2: string;

    constructor() {
        this.CritterProperty1 = "n ne e se s so o no".split(" ");        
    }

    // Critter methods ...
}

type legendObjectType = Critter | Wall;

interface Ilegend {
    [k: string]: legendObjectType; 
}

// i've got an issue to define the type of 'theLegend' Object
let theLegend: Ilegend = {
    "X": Wall,
    "o": Critter
}
```

> error TS2322: Type '{ "X": typeof Wall; "o": typeof Critter; }' is not
>   assignable to type 'Ilegend'.

while i can compile it, if the "Class Wall" is empty.

does anyone know how to define the type of such a class's collection?

> let theLegend = {
>       "X": Wall,
>       "o": Critter }

(this is an exemple from the chapter 7 of [eloquent javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/07_elife.html), than i try to transcribe in typescript)

**EDIT**

i complete the Rico Kahler's answer, with an abstract Class to avoid using the union type

```
abstract class MapItem {
    originChar: string;

    constructor(){}
}

class Wall extends MapItem {
    brick: string;

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.brick = "jolies briques oranges";
    }

    // Wall methods ...
}

class Critter extends MapItem {
    CritterProperty1: string[];
    CritterProperty2: string;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.CritterProperty1 = "n ne e se s so o no".split(" ");        
    }

    // Critter methods ...
}

interface Ilegend {
    [k: string]: new () => MapItem; 
}

let theLegend: Ilegend = {
    "X": Wall,
    "o": Critter
}
```

thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue lies your object `theLegend`.

Typescript is expect an *instance* of Wall or Critter but instead you're providing it with a type.

```
let theLegend: Ilegend = {
    "X": Wall, // `Wall` is a type not an instance, it is `typeof Wall` or the Wall type
    "o": Critter // `Criter` is a type not an instance
}
```

Something like the following will work:

```
let theLegend: Ilegend = {
    X: new Wall(), // now it's an instance!
    o: new Critter()
}
```

**Edit:**

Now reading the javascript pages you linked, it seems like I missed your intent. If you want to create an interface that takes a constructor, then I would type `Ilegend` as follows:

```
interface Legend {
    [k: string]: new () => (Critter | Wall)
}

// now you can define an object with this type

let legend: Legend = {
    // here `Critter` actually refers to the class constructor
    // that conforms to the type `new () => (Critter | Wall)` instead of just a type
    something: Critter,
    somethingElse: Wall
}

const critter = new legend.something() // creates a `Critter`
const wall = new legend.somethingElse() // creates a `Wall`

// however, the type of `critter` and `wall` are both `Critter | Wall`. You'd have to use type assertion (i.e. casting) because typescript can't tell if its either a Critter or a Wall
```

Now the interfaces allows any string to be a key and it expects every value to be a function that you can call `new` on to get either a `Critter` or a `Wall`